# Validating empty Guids in Api layer

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Let's say I have an API endpoint `GET api/customers`. My API request model contains a `Guid`.

In the business layer I throw an error if that Guid is **empty**.

- Should I catch this error in the API layer or let it propagate to lower layers?
- Should I check that Guid against empty in the API layer?

  - using annotations
  - classic if check, before calling the business logic
- Is there any standard way to handle empty Guids in API design?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to define as `Nullable<Guid>` in your request API model.

So that it will have `null` value instead of empty.

And you can add also checking logic into your API Controller before calling business logic.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I don't want to make the Guid nullable though, since it is a required parameter in my request.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking a Controller's Action should be responsible for the followings:

1. Receive and try parse data (header, route, form)
2. Perform preliminary checks
3. Call service / business layer
4. Translate the response from the below layer to a http response

In my opinion checking against `Guid.Empty` is the same as checking against whitespaces or `null`. If the provided data does not met the requirements then the best thing what you can do is to **fail fast** or use *fallback*.

I have participated in several discussions about where this kind of validation should belong. As always it depends. But my personal rule of thumb (I have followed this through many projects) looks like this:

- Presentation layer should check against syntactic issues (check against default values as well)
- Business layer should check against semantic issues (cross property / cross entity checks as well)
- Persistence layer should check against dataset consistency

My point is that at the end of the day you want to have the followings:

- Responsibilities of different layers are understood by everyone
- Each validation logic can be easily determined where it should belong
- Validation failures can be easily tracked back